# Can't read file from android internal storage into byte array

Tags: android, arrays, readfile

I am trying to save a p12 file to internal storage like so:

```
    File file = new File(mContext.getFilesDir(), "fileName.p12");
```

I then proceed to read this file into a byte array like so:

```
    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        bFile = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After doing this, I get a FileNotFoundException even though the debugger shows that the file is saved in /data/data/com.fm.sg.android/files/fileName.p12

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you print `file.getAbsolutePath()` to LogCat, what does it show you?

Comment: Nvm, found my issue. It was unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().toString(); 
String filename = "fileName.p12"; 
File file = new File(path,filename);
```

then the rest of your code....this should make it...